# Laravel pusher notification not giving error but pusher does not notify

Tags: laravel, pusher

I am trying to use pusher for notifications, and when I make a request I see no error, however, the notification does not work.

Controller:

```php
public function requestCommunityMembership(Request $request, Community $community){

    $user = $this->getAuthorizedUser($request->header('X-User-Auth-Token'));
    //$user = User::find(6999);
    if (!$user) {
        return response()->json(['error' => true, 'code' => 401, 'message' => INVALID_AUTH_TOKEN], 401);
    }

    $data = [
        'sender_id' => $user->id,
        'type' => 'notification',
        'type_id' => null,
        'title' => null,
        'receiver_id' => $community->user_id,
        'message' => null,
        'sent_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    ];

    $app_notification = AppNotification::create($data);

    event(new SendCommunityMembershipNotification($community));

    return response()->json(['error' => false, 'code' => 200, 'message' => $app_notification], 200);

}
```

The notification looks like this:

```php
class SendCommunityMembershipNotification
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    protected $community;

    public function __construct($community)
    {
        $this->community = $community;
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'new-membership-request-event';
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        $channel = 'golfplayed-new-membership-request-' . $this->community->user_id;

        return new Channel($channel);
    }
}
```

My broadcasting.php looks like this:

```php
'pusher' => [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => 'usss',
        'encrypted' => true
    ],
],
```

And the rest is in the .env

```php
PUSHER_APP_NAME=gnameed
PUSHER_APP_ID=XXXXX
PUSHER_APP_KEY=YYYYYY
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=ZZZZZZZZZ
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=usss
```

Is there anything else I must add to make my notification work?

Updated: I just updated my question with the notification code

Comment: You have pasted the same code of your controller in the notification. Update yout answer to see the notificacion code. Maybe has something to do with the queue.

Comment: By the way, maybe is a typo or trying to hide your real settings (good choice) but the only available clusters that I can see in the Pusher [documentation](https://pusher.com/docs/clusters) are: `mt1`, `us2`, `eu`, `ap1` and `ap2`.. you are specifying: `usss`

Comment: @HCK was just tryng to hide. but am using us2

Comment: @Thank you, I just edited my question and the notification code is there now

Comment: Did you also updated the `default` key in the `config/broadcasting.php` to set Pusher as your main driver? `'default' => 'pusher'` or in your `.env`: `BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher`. By default Laravel uses the log driver.

Comment: I changed the broadcast_driver in the .env to pusher